# variable not recognized outside the case statement

Tags: scala, apache-spark, functional-programming, switch-statement, pattern-matching

Please help me understand why the variable 'afd' is not recognized outside the case statement. I run the code below, and get the error below: Thanks!

```
1 match {
  case 0 => "zero"
  case 1 => val afd = "one"
}

afd.show()

res1784: Any = ()
<console>:492: error: not found: value afd
       afd.show()
       ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems. Firstly, you're trying to reach `afd` value outside of scope. It's defined within `match` statement and only accessible there (in this specific `case`). `match` returns value, so you can use something like:

```
val afd = 1 match {
  case 0 => "zero"
  case 1 => "one"
}
```

Secondly, even if it was reachable outside of `match`, `afd` is of type `String` and `String` doesn't have `show` method. You would have to print it using for example `print(afd)`.

Comment: Thank you ! I know what you mean now. The actual problem uses a data frame, I just simplified to make it easier on the reader, how would you handle the match if it is a dataframe?  is there an alternative that would allow me to reach the variable outside the scope of the match?